# not updating multiple check for role section php

Tags: php

I have role section with read,write,delete operations but when i check all checking its not showing all checked but i showing only one if i uncheck one its showing different but not correct i think my code is wrong what am i doing wrong or please redo code or can i have code according to my picture.any help would be highly appreciated

```
           <form method="post" action="insertuser.php" class="form-horizontal">
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
                                <thead>
                                   <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">No</th>
                                    <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Menu Name</th>
                                    <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Read</th>
                                    <th data-field="actions" data-sortable="true">Edit</th>
                                    <th data-field="actions" data-sortable="true">Delete</th>

                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $i=1;
                                $selectquery=mysql_query("select * from menumanagement");
                                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($selectquery))
                                {
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php  echo $i++;   ?></td>
                                        <td><?php  echo  $row["mn_menuname"]; ?></td>    
                                        <td>
                                         <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline checked">
                                                    <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fa fa-square-o"></span><span class="second-icon fa fa-check-square-o"></span></span><input type="checkbox"  name="read1[]" id="read1" value="1_<?php  echo  $row["mn_id"]; ?>">
                                                </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                         <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline checked">
                                                    <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fa fa-square-o"></span><span class="second-icon fa fa-check-square-o"></span></span><input type="checkbox" name="edit1[]" id="edit1" value="1_<?php  echo  $row["mn_id"]; ?>">
                                                </label>
                                        </td>
                                         <td>
                                          <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline checked">
                                                    <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fa fa-square-o"></span><span class="second-icon fa fa-check-square-o"></span></span><input type="checkbox"  name="delete1[]" id="delete1" value="1_<?php  echo  $row["mn_id"]; ?>">
                                                </label>
                                         </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                }

                                    ?>

</form>

if($_POST["read1"])
{
    $countread=count($_POST["read1"]);
    for($i=0;$i<$countread;$i++)
    {
     $read1=$_POST["read1"][$i];

    $readdiv=explode("_", $read1);
    echo 'read'.$readid=$readdiv[0];
    echo '<br>read'.$readid1=$readdiv[1];
    }
}

if($_POST["edit1"])
{
    $countedit=count($_POST["edit1"]);
    for($i=0;$i<$countedit;$i++)
    {
     $edit1=$_POST["edit1"][$i];

    $editdiv=explode("_", $edit1);
    echo 'edit'.$editid=$editdiv[0];
    echo '<br>edit'.$editid1=$editdiv[1];
    }

}

if($_POST["delete1"])
{
    $countdelete=count($_POST["delete1"]);
    for($i=0;$i<$countdelete;$i++)
    {
     $delete1=$_POST["delete1"][$i];

    $deletediv=explode("_", $delete1);
    echo 'edit'.$deleteid=$deletediv[0];
    echo '<br>edit'.$deleteid1=$deletediv[1];
    }

}
```

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take value with dynamic ids. Use `value="<?php echo $i."_".$row["mn_id"]; ?>"` in checkbox values.

Try Below code:

**HTML Code:**

```
<?php
    $i=1;
    $selectquery=mysql_query("select * from menumanagement");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($selectquery))
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php  echo $i;   ?></td>
            <td><?php  echo  $row["mn_menuname"]; ?></td>    
            <td>
             <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline checked">
                        <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fa fa-square-o"></span><span class="second-icon fa fa-check-square-o"></span></span><input type="checkbox"  name="read1[]" id="read1" value="<?php  echo  $i."_".$row["mn_id"]; ?>">
                    </label>
            </td>
            <td>
             <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline checked">
                        <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fa fa-square-o"></span><span class="second-icon fa fa-check-square-o"></span></span><input type="checkbox" name="edit1[]" id="edit1" value="<?php  echo  $i."_".$row["mn_id"]; ?>">
                    </label>
            </td>
             <td>
              <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline checked">
                        <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fa fa-square-o"></span><span class="second-icon fa fa-check-square-o"></span></span><input type="checkbox"  name="delete1[]" id="delete1" value="<?php  echo  $i."_".$row["mn_id"]; ?>">
                    </label>
             </td>

        </tr>
        <?php
        $i++;   
    }

        ?>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
if($_POST["read1"])
{
    $countread=count($_POST["read1"]);
    for($i=0;$i<$countread;$i++)
    {
     $read1=$_POST["read1"][$i];

    $readdiv=explode("_", $read1);
    echo 'read'.$readid=$readdiv[0];
    echo '<br>read'.$readid1=$readdiv[1];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sure i am checking in my system please wait thank you

Comment: Its seems worked not sure but i will update status thank you for your help